# Upgrade from SpringBoot 2.4.2 to 2.7.0 - SSL issue - Server not coming up - Multiple certificates specified, missing required attribute

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, tomcat9

Our SpringBoot application is SSL enabled and everything was working as expected with SpringBoot 2.4.2 (which uses Tomcat 9.0.41). Our application uses embedded Tomcat server.

We recently upgraded to SpringBoot 2.7.0 (which uses Tomcat 9.0.63) and with SSL enabled the server never comes up.

The exception seems similar to the one mentioned here: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62803

Our application.properties file:

```
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN server.ssl.protocol=TLS
server.ssl.key-password=<PASSWORD>
server.ssl.key-store-password=<PASSWORD> server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-alias=<ALIAS> server.port=<PORT>
server.ssl.key-store-type=jks server.ssl.key-store=<CERTIFICATE FILE PATH>
```

We see below exception during startup:

```
2022-08-22 08:09:03,472 [main] WARN  o.a.t.u.IntrospectionUtils - Error setting property [keystoreProvider] to [SUN] on class [class org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.setProperty(IntrospectionUtils.java:80) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:?]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.setProperty(IntrospectionUtils.java:48) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:?]
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.setProperty(Connector.java:309) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:?]
  at com.xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz.v1.EPCustomServletContainer$1.customize(EPCustomServletContainer.java:67) ~[classes!/:1.0]
  at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.customizeConnector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:347) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
  at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:203) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:184) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
  at com.xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz.v1.EPApplicationStartup.main(EPApplicationStartup.java:102) ~[classes!/:1.0]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
  at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[extproc-wfr-1.0.jar:1.0]
  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[extproc-wfr-1.0.jar:1.0]
  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[extproc-wfr-1.0.jar:1.0]
  at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[extproc-wfr-1.0.jar:1.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple certificates were specified and at least one is missing the required attribute type
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfig.addCertificate(SSLHostConfig.java:258) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:?]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfig.registerDefaultCertificate(SSLHostConfig.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:?]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfig.setCertificateKeystoreProvider(SSLHostConfig.java:595) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:?]
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.setKeystoreProvider(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:969) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:?]
  ... 26 more
```

I have tried forcing the Tomcat version to be 9.0.41 and also 9.0.65 with SpringBoot 2.7.0 in the POM file and still I am noticing the same issue.

Any help on how to I resolve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to check your keystore file with "keytool -list -keystore your_file" to validate values. And AFAIK "server.ssl.key-store-provider" property is not needed

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, the keystore file is also the same. If I switch to springboot-2.4.2, the same keystore file works. Also, I removed "server.ssl.key-store-provider" this property, still no luck. Thanks for your response!

Comment: perhaps newer version of Tomcat is more strict to a bad keystore file... Please doublecheck the file, it is complaining about "Multiple certificates ..." - make sure that you have only needed ones. Regenerate it if possible

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue.

We have a custom connector implemented for decrypting the keystore and key passwords from the application.properties file. This implementation is very similar to how it has been shown in this link: https://frugalisminds.com/how-to-configure-ssl-in-spring-boot-2/

However, trying to set the properties/attributes on the new custom connector was causing this issue:

```
connector.setAttribute("keyAlias", <alias>);
connector.setAttribute("keystorePass", <password>);
connector.setAttribute("keystoreFile", <file>);
```

So, instead of adding custom connector and setting the values, I am modifying the default connector itself as below:

```
public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
  if (Boolean.valueOf(sslEnabled)) {
    // Force the passwords in the default connector to be updated with decrypted passwords
    factory.getSsl().setKeyPassword(<key-password>);
    factory.getSsl().setKeyStorePassword(<keystore-password>);
  }
}
```

Hope this help, thanks!